# How to use promise using mocha and chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js

First, I made dummy data.

```
interface Student {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const students: Student[] = [
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Sean Grey',
    age: 24
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Sllllean Grey',
    age: 224
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Seansdajfklajs Grey',
    age: 2114
  }
];

export default students;
```

Second, this is my controller api on nodejs.

```
import express from 'express';
import students from '../../dummy/students';

class StudentController {
  static getAllStudents(req: express.Request, res: express.Response) {
    return res.status(200).json({
      students,
      message: 'All the students'
    });
  }
}

export default StudentController;
```

Lastly, I made test code like below using mocha and chai on nodejs.

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';
import Index from '../index';

chai.use(chaiHttp);
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();

describe('Students', () => {
  describe('GET /', () => {
    it('Should get all students record', done => {
      chai
        .request(Index)
        .get('/')
        .end((err, res) => {
          return Promise.all([
            res.should.have.status(200),
            res.body.should.be.a('object'),
            done()
          ]);
        });
    });
  })
})
```

But when I run this all code, it gives me an error " Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For
async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves".
I don't know how to solve this problem. Could you recommend some advice? Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: Why are you returning a `Promise.all` in `end` chain. And simply check for `res.should.have.status(200)` and others straightaway without that `return` of `promise`.

Comment: I don't understand well. Could you write the code you said?

Comment: What @ambianBeing is telling you is there is no reason to use a promise here (let alone promise.all)

Comment: Meant to say this: `.end((err, res) => {
 res.should.have.status(200);
 res.body.should.be.a('object');
 done();
});` that pretty sure return of `Promise.all` is not required.

Comment: if you do want to use promises then you should do it like this:

`it('Should be amazing" , async()=>{const res = await someAsyncFunction()}`

Comment: @amianBeing.end((err, res) => { res.should.have.status(200); res.body.should.be.a('object'); done(); });    I used this without promise.all . But result is same. Could you recommend some solution?

Comment: @DDDD Is the API working properly as a check have you tested it with postman or browser.

Comment: yes, the api works well by postman.

Comment: @DDDD That's weird! Do you get any error while using this (passing error to done) `.end((err, res) => { if (err) done(err); res.should.have.status(200); res.body.should.be.a('object'); done(); });` . Apart from what u're already getting.